# Fluctuations in the HH Model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, neuroscience

The Hodgkin Huxley Model describes the voltage that flows through a membrane of a nerve cell - this voltage is subject to arbitrary fluctuations that result from the stochastic closing and opening of ion channels. Now it is the case that in a certain area of the membrane - let's say A, are N ion channels. According to statistics, the fluctuations in the current should increase with root of N.

I will write briefly why this is so:

Let's say the probability that a channel is open is p, that it is closed (1-p) - so we assume it is open or closed - thus the ion channel is a binomially distributed stochastic quantity.

We assume that the opening of the ion channels is independent of each other, so the probability that k channels are open and (N-k) channels are closed can be represented simply by the classic distribution function of the binomial distribution, which has been known since school. Now suppose a current of strength i flows through a channel, then a current of strength ki flows through k channels and now we know that (Theorem Moivre Laplace) for large N is the expected value for k = pN and the fluctuations in k with the root of N grow.

Now I have written a simple code for the HH model, in which the area is gradually increased, but the fluctuations do not grow ... can you look over and make a suggestion how to measure the fluctuations in v sensibly? The RMS value is decreasing with the area - but I want to show the absolute fluctuations... they should increase

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf,ccf




    def HHmodel(I,length, area):

            v = []
            m = []
            h = []
            n = []
            dt = 0.05
            t = np.linspace(0,100,length)


            #constants
            Cm = 1.0#microFarad
            ENa=50 #miliVolt
            EK=-77  #miliVolt
            El=-54 #miliVolt
            g_Na=120 #mScm-2
            g_K=36 #mScm-2
            g_l=0.03 #mScm-2

            def alphaN(v):
                return 0.01*(v+50)/(1-np.exp(-(v+50)/10))

            def betaN(v):
                return 0.125*np.exp(-(v+60)/80)

            def alphaM(v):
                return 0.1*(v+35)/(1-np.exp(-(v+35)/10))

            def betaM(v):
                return 4.0*np.exp(-0.0556*(v+60))

            def alphaH(v):
                return 0.07*np.exp(-0.05*(v+60))

            def betaH(v):
                return 1/(1+np.exp(-(0.1)*(v+30)))

            #Initialize the voltage and the channels :
            v.append(-60)
            m0 = alphaM(v[0])/(alphaM(v[0])+betaM(v[0]))
            n0 = alphaN(v[0])/(alphaN(v[0])+betaN(v[0]))
            h0 = alphaH(v[0])/(alphaH(v[0])+betaH(v[0]))

            #t.append(0)
            m.append(m0)
            n.append(n0)
            h.append(h0)

            #solving ODE using Euler's method:
            for i in range(1,len(t)):
                m.append(m[i-1] + dt*((alphaM(v[i-1])*(1-m[i-1]))-betaM(v[i-1])*m[i-1]))
                n.append(n[i-1] + dt*((alphaN(v[i-1])*(1-n[i-1]))-betaN(v[i-1])*n[i-1]))
                h.append(h[i-1] + dt*((alphaH(v[i-1])*(1-h[i-1]))-betaH(v[i-1])*h[i-1]))
                gNa = g_Na * h[i-1]*(m[i-1])**3
                gK=g_K*n[i-1]**4
                gl=g_l
                INa = gNa*(v[i-1]-ENa)
                IK = gK*(v[i-1]-EK)
                Il=gl*(v[i-1]-El)
                v.append(v[i-1]+(dt)*((1/Cm)*((I[i-1]*np.sqrt(area))-(INa+IK+Il))))
                r.append(np.log(abs(v[i]))-np.log(abs(v[i-1])))


            squares = np.sum(j**2 for j in v)/len(v)
            rmsvalue = np.sqrt(squares)



            return v,area,rmsvalue





    length = 100*5  #the time period


    output = []
    rms_output = []

    itteration = 10

    r = []
    rt = []


    for j in range(0,itteration):
        barcode = np.zeros(length)
        noisyI = np.random.normal(0,9,length)
        area = 1.0+0.1*j
        res = HHmodel(noisyI,length,area)
        output.append(res[0])
        rms_output.append(res[2])



    plt.plot(res[2])
    plt.show()



    print('Done.')
```